# Survival curve for Cox regression of multiple imputated data

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, mice

I have a question. I am trying to plot an adjusted Kaplan Meyer curve, that is a survival curve after having performed a regression and a multiple imputation.

For that, I need to use the `survfit` function on a Cox regression obtained with mulitple imputation.
Here is an example code

```
library(data.table)
library(mice)
library(data.table)
library(Hmisc)
dummyex <- data.table(treatment_duration = sample(c(1:10), 50, replace = T), 
                     stopany = sample(c(0,1),50,replace = T), 
                     ID = 1:50
                     )
dummyex[,seropositive := sample(c(0,1),1),by = ID]
head(dummyex)
   treatment_duration stopany ID seropositive
1:                  9       1  1            1
2:                  1       0  2            0
3:                  7       1  3            1
4:                  1       1  4            1
5:                  2       1  5            1
6:                  8       0  6            0
```

I make some missing data

```
dummyex[sample(c(1:length(dummyex$ID)), length(dummyex$ID)*0.1 ), names(dummyex) := NA] # here I make some missing data
```

so I can make the multiple imputation

```
dummy_impute <- mice(dummyex, m=10,method="pmm",maxit=20) # here is the multiple imputation
```

and the fit

```
coxfit <- fit.mult.impute(Surv(treatment_duration,stopany) ~ seropositive, fitter=coxph,xtrans=dummy_impute,data=dummyex)
```

Until here no problem. I would like to do what works on regular Cox regression, that is

```
survfit(coxfit, newdata = data.frame(seropositive = 1) )
```

or

```
survfit(coxfit, newdata = dummyex[,seropositive := 1] )
```

Both give me

```
Error in survfit.coxph(coxfit, newdata = predict) : 
  Could not reconstruct the y vector
```

I am stuck here, I didn't find any clear answer. Any help would be Highly appreciated.

to compare with regular Cox regression:

```
coxfitsimple <- coxph(Surv(treatment_duration,stopany) ~ seropositive, data=dummyex) 
survfit(coxfitsimple,newdata = data.frame(seropositive = 1))

Call: survfit(formula = coxfitsimple, newdata = data.frame(seropositive = 1))

      n  events  median 0.95LCL 0.95UCL 
     45      28       9       7      NA
```

works like a charm. I don't get it because the multiple imputation coxfit is of class coxph

```
> class(coxfit)
[1] "fit.mult.impute" "coxph"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that is not correct but do part of the job:

```
dummy_cox_impute <- mice::complete(dummy_impute,"long",include = T)
coxfit2 <- coxph(Surv(treatment_duration,stopany) ~ seropositive,data = dummy_cox_impute)
testimpute <- survfit(coxfit2, newdata = data.frame(seropositive = 1))
```

The variance is wrong, but the mean KM curve is right.

Comment: This is direct pooling as I alluded to in my answer. To obtain correct CIs just correct the sample size inflation by multiplying the halfwidths by N=$\sqrt(10)$ (the number of imputations in the long format).

Comment: Thank you. It will not be totally right as it doesn't take into account the variance inflation due to the mice imputation, but it will be indeed better

Comment: I think deriving a Rubin's Rules type estimator for the confidence bounds of a quantile estimator from multiply imputed data is too much (it may exist, but to pore over the math is beyond me). The only other suggestion I might have is to just fit a piecewise exponential survival model. A parametric survival curve is directly a function of the parameter estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically this can't be done directly because the multiply imputed fit is different from a single fit as presented in a normal Cox model. When multiple imputation is performed, several possible datasets are generated and the model fitting process combines those fits into a single point estimate. If you wish to obtain survival curves from the survival outcomes and possible stratifying variables used to estimate the Cox model, you will have to estimate the survival curve for each of the Cox models and combine them in some "sane" way. This is methodologically unclear. You could consider a point-wise average, a maximum, or reconstruct the risk sets to directly pool the survival outcomes. There is no clear answer here, but each approach is defensible yet imperfect.

Comment: thank you. I tried a solution that is basically one of your suggestion. Thanks for helping